# How to convert a rational number like 1.6 to the higher integer number?

Tags: google-sheets

How can i convert the number 1.6 to 2, 3.8 to 4 and 1.2 to 2. Any number that has0.0 to be converted to the next number . Round will round the number to the nearest integer but I want to the higher integer except when the number has no decimal portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer
`=roundup()` that will round the number to higher digit even if its less than 0.5